# dissolving background images for header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header class in my CSS that looks like this-

```
header {
    background-image: url('../img/header-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    .background-cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    .intro-text {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        .intro-lead-in {
            .serif-font;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: 22px;
            line-height: 22px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }
        .intro-heading {
            .heading-font;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }
    }
}
```

now I want the background image here to change in every 10 seconds with a second file named say '`abc.jpg`'.
the solutions given online suggest having two `<img>` tags in the html code and then using jquery to perform the transition.
but my html code does not contain any `<img>` tag as I have defined the image in the CSSfor header.
so now how can this transition be done without adding additional img tags in the html codes?
Or is there any way that i can manipulate the CSS file using jQuery or Javascript and change the url for background-image for the header class after every 10 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .b1 { background-image: url("img1.jpg"); height:100%;width:100% }
    .b2 { background-image: url("img2.jpg"); height:100%;width:100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function(){
    function run(interval, frames) {
        var int = 1;
        function func() {
            document.getElementById("mydiv").setAttribute("class", "b"+int);
            int++;
            if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
        }
        var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
    }
    run(1000, 3); //milliseconds, frames
    }//]]> 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="mydiv">
 here is the div with auto change backgroud of header
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your html like this

```
<header id="change-image" style="background-image: url('../img/header-bg.jpg');"></header>
```

Now you have style property that you can change, only one rule is there, all other keep in external less